# Create a mutable array of arrays each containing a dictionary in swift?

Tags: swift

I am trying to declare a variable that stores an array of arrays. Each array then contains a Dictionary object. I tried a bunch of different possible declarations but the compiler is not happy with any of them.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Clarification on what I needed:

An array that contains arrays where each of them contains dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Said

> Each array then contains a Dictionary object

that mean that each array will have a single Dictionary so why do you need that extra Array

anyway  the following code declare an Array that contain Dictionaries(The code assume that eventually your dictionary will contain strings but you can change that to any type you want)

```
var myObj  = Array<Dictionary<String,String>>()

var dic1:Dictionary<String,String> = Dictionary<String,String>()
dic1["A"] = "Alpha :A"
dic1["B"] = "Alpha :B"


var dic2:Dictionary<String,String> = Dictionary<String,String>()
dic2["C"] = "Alpha :C"
dic2["D"] = "Alpha :D"

myObj.append(dic1)
myObj.append(dic2)
```

if you need an array containing arrays of dictionaries it will be almost the same

```
var myObj  = Array<Array<Dictionary<String,String>>>()
```

Comment: this works. I ended up making it an optional because of what I need to do so I used: "var cars:[[Dictionary<String, String>]]?"

Comment: The compiler seems to accept your solution it seems to be equivalent to  Array<Array<Dictionary<String,String>>>() , i still prefer my way maybe because I am coming from java background so it seems natural to me.

Comment: @zumzum: You could even go nuts and use `var cars: [[[String: String]]] = []`. I'd suggest you reconsider making the array optional -- it adds a bit of extra work, and an empty array can have essentially the same meaning as a `nil` optional value.